# get total value of incremented input box

Tags: php, sql

so i have an incremented input box and what i wanted to do is to get the total value on the input box.

example

```
 <input type="text" id="dr_1" name="dr_1[]" value = 2000/>
 <input type="text" id="dr_1" name="dr_1[]" value = 3000/>
 <input type="text" id="dr_1" name="dr_1[]" value = 5000/>
```

what i wanted is to get the total of this.

```
if (isset($_POST['creditpay'])) {
    $dr = $_POST['dr_1'];
    $user_id_2 = $_POST['user_id_2'];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($dr); $i++) { 
            $tt = $amount_2[$i];
            $res = $db->update_user_credit($tt,$user_id_2);     
    }
}
```

this is my php code but it only gets the each value not the total.. is there a way?.

Comment: tt = $amount_2[$i];? what does this do?

Comment: it only get all the value from the input box each. separately.

Comment: On a side note - you can't have the same `id` for multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

```
$a = array(5,15,25);
echo array_sum($a); // Will Output 45
```

In your example it should be as below, outside `for` loop

```
$total = array_sum($_POST['dr_1']);
```

**Edited**

```
if (isset($_POST['creditpay'])) {
    $dr = $_POST['dr_1'];
    $total = array_sum($dr); // Get total
    $user_id_2 = $_POST['user_id_2'];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($dr); $i++) { 
        $tt = $amount_2[$i];
        $res = $db->update_user_credit($tt,$user_id_2);     
    }
}
```

Comment: but i needed the loop.because each `dr_1` have diffrent value. i tried it and i got nothing..

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and check the data you get. Also in your HTML, there is no attribute as `value1, value2, value3`. Change it to `value` for all 3 `input` boxes.

Comment: ohh i forgot to remove the numbers on the value befor i posted it.. my bad.

Comment: i got the result but it's kinda weird..`60000nullfalse` it shows like this

Comment: it sums up the values but for no reason there is nullfalse next to it.